# Understanding certain ELF file structure

Tags: c, gcc, linker, arm, elf

From ARM's infocenter, regarding section [static linking and relocations](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dai0242a/BCGEAIAB.html):

```
** Section #1 'ER_RO' (SHT_PROGBITS) [SHF_ALLOC + SHF_EXECINSTR]
Size : 28 bytes (alignment 4)
Address: 0x00008000
$a
.text
bar
    0x00008000: E59f000C .... LDR r0,[pc,#12] ; [0x8014] = 0x801C
    0x00008004: E5901000 .... LDR r1,[r0,#0]
    0x00008008: E2411001 ..A. SUB r1,r1,#1
    0x0000800C: E5801000 .... STR r1,[r0,#0]
    0x00008010: E12FFF1E ../. BX lr
$d
    0x00008014: 0000801C .... DCD 32796
$a
.text
foo
    0x00008018: EAFFFFF8 .... B bar ; 0x8000
```

and from [ELF for the ARM architecture](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0044f/IHI0044F_aaelf.pdf):

> Table 4-7, Mapping symbols
> Name Meaning
> $a -     Start of a sequence of ARM instructions
> $d -    Start of a sequence of data items (for example, a literal pool)

As you can see, the `ELF` file contains a section in which there is code (`bar`), then data/ro (`32796`), then more code (`foo`) in consecutive addresses.

Now, a basic principle regarding any SW file structure is that the SW is composed from different and separate sections - `text` (code), `data`, and `bss`. (and `rodata` if we want to be pedantic) as we can see if we examine the `MAP` file.

So, this ELF structure is not consistent with this basic principle, so my question is what is going on here? am I mistaking in this basic principle? if not, than is this `ELF` structure will be changed in run time to meet the sections separation?
and why is the `ELF` section contains mixed types in a certain sequential address space?

**NOTE:** I assume the scatter file used in the example is the default one since the document contains the example do not provide any scatter file along with the example.

Comment: Why would the elf file care about those sections to start with?  That is a compiler internals notion.  Elf and other file formats are about loading the binary.  Obviously if you do an objdump of an elf file it shows you each of the sections,  the info is there keep digging.  But loading is more interesting, if the sections are combined into a linear loadable chunk I would hope the file has those in a single chunk (PROGBITS).

Comment: I would worry more about generic elf than the arm documentation initially, then if you find something not covered in generic elf, then reach out to arm documentation.

Comment: Likewise you are confusing arm documentation on arms toolchain with possibly the gnu toolchain?  separate toolchains, can follow whatever rules they want in different ways so long as the provide correct results (meaning they implement the code per the language you are using into something that is functionally correct).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At run time, the sections do not matter, only the `PT_LOAD` segments in the program header.  The ELF specification is quite flexible there as well, but some loaders have restrictions on the `PT_LOAD` segments they can process.

The reason for splitting code and data this way could be that this architecture supports only a limited range of PC-relative addressing and needs a constant pool for loading most constants (because constructing them via immediates is too expensive).  Having as few large constants pools as possible is attractive because it leads to improved data and instruction cache utilization (instead of caching memory which is not of the right type and this can never be used), but you may still need more than one if the code size exceeds what can be addressed directly.